# Node.js windows service , cannot spawn GUI app from service

Tags: windows, node.js, windows-services

I am running a Node.js application inside a windows service using [NSSM](http://nssm.cc/) , Once a day i check a remote API and spawn an executable file that pops a notification balloon in the system tray .
When i run this from a console session this works as expected , but when running from a windows service , i see the notification executable in running processes list , but the balloon does not show up . I guess that a service isn't supposed to have a user interface .
But there must be a way to do it ..

When i run `services.msc` , Select my service > Properties > Log On > Mark 'Allow service to interact with desktop` does not help .

The code is : `spawn("notify.exe", {cwd: path.resolve(__dirname, "/tools")});`

What can cause such behavior ?

Comment: A code would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are running headlong into ["Session 0 Isolation"](http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#WhatIsSession0Isolation), a security enhancement present in Windows Vista and later. The notification balloon in the system tray created by your service will never be shown on any user's desktop irrespective of the ["Allow service to interact with desktop" setting, which is now misleading](http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#InteractWithDesktop).